# How to anchor an iframe video player to the bottom,left, and right position? HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am mainly familiar with c# .NET and in .NET I know that you can anchor controls to the different positions on the form. I was wondering if there was a way to anchor an iframe player to all the sides of the webpage except for the top? So overall, I want all sides of the player to be attached to the left,right and bottom sides of the webpage. Will I have to get the size of the webpage or is there an actual setting that I can put in my code? I am new to HTML and JavaScript and am working hard on creating a website for fun.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Using CSS you can set the iframe to display:absolute; width:100%; bottom:0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use CSS.

```
display: fixed; /* absolute, if the page has non-fixed height */
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

But if you need to do this, it's virtually guaranteed that you're trying to make something horrible, so I'd recommend not doing this =)

Comment: i was going to apply css later but where would i put this code? Like javascript needs to be in the script tags. Do i need to do something similar?

Comment: @Aaron: yes, you need to put the CSS in a <style> tag or you need to put the CSS in a .css file and link that file to the page. The latter is the recommended option.

Comment: okay, that makes sense. what do i do put to call the iframe though? .iframe?

Comment: now we're heading into "how do I HTML" territory, for which google is a better friend than stackoverflow.